# how can I create a stored procedure sql workbench that uses a redshift database?

Tags: amazon-redshift, sql-workbench-j

is it possible to create a stored procedures on  sql workbench that uses a redshift database ?

I tried to put in some procedure found on the internet like this one

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION proc_sample RETURN INTEGER
IS
  l_result INTEGER;
BEGIN
  SELECT max(col1) INTO l_result FROM sometable;
  RETURN l_result;
END;
```

but I get an error 
the cursor is not located inside a statement

help please.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my translation of your stored procedure for Redshift:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE proc_sample (
      l_result  OUT  INTEGER
)
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
BEGIN
  SELECT max(col1) INTO l_result FROM sometable;
END
$$;
```

You call this stored procedure in Redshift as follows:

```
BEGIN; CALL proc_sample(); END;
--  l_result
-- ----------
--        99
```

For more information see ["Overview of stored procedures in Amazon Redshift"](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/stored-procedure-create.html)

Answer (score 0):

you can not use from clause in function. you have to use procedure  having parameter with out clause.